# I need to insert Data in Grid view dynamically without using database

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have created a web form in ASP.NET in which i'm taking some data from the user through the form so that when he/she will click the submit button then that data will be shown there in a gridview which will be binded using empty data table and a view state variable.But when i fill all the data and press the submit button then no row is added and the code doesn't get executed the way i desired it to be. below is the code:
for .aspx

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    
        Welcome To My First Web Form<br />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Candidate Registration Form</h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Applicant&#39;s Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" EnableViewState="False" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Please enter Your Name!" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Applicant's FName"></asp:Label>
        :&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="Please enter your Father name!" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Gender"></asp:Label>:&nbsp;<asp:RadioButtonList ID="gender" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"  runat="server" Width="141px" RepeatLayout="Flow"> <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="gender" ErrorMessage="Please Choose your Gender" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;
        <br />
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="E-mail ID"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;:&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox3_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="E-mail address is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
&nbsp;
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="E-mail addresses must be in the format of name@domain.xyz" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ForeColor="Red">Invalid Format</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        <br />
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="password"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;:&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox4" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Password is Required!" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Confirm Password"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;:&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox5" ErrorMessage="The passwords Didn't Match!" ForeColor="Red" ControlToCompare="TextBox4" Display="Dynamic"></asp:CompareValidator>
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EmptyDataText="please fill the data" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

now for .cs file is as:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

namespace WebApplication5
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Name"), new DataColumn("FatherName"), new DataColumn("E-mail") });
                ViewState["Candidates"] = dt;
                this.BindGrid();
            }
        }
        

        protected void TextBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["Candidates"];
            dt.Rows.Add(TextBox1.Text.Trim(), TextBox2.Text.Trim(),TextBox3.Text.Trim());
            ViewState["Candidates"] = dt;
            TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            TextBox2.Text = string.Empty;
            TextBox3.Text = string.Empty;

        }

        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void BindGrid()
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState["Candidates"];
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    
    }
}
```

Just try to ignore those &nbsp help me figure out what's exactly the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `BindGrid()` method on the button click and your code will work.
Your modified button click will be like this.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["Candidates"];
     dt.Rows.Add(TextBox1.Text.Trim(), TextBox2.Text.Trim(),TextBox3.Text.Trim());
     ViewState["Candidates"] = dt;
     TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
     TextBox2.Text = string.Empty;
     TextBox3.Text = string.Empty;
     BindGrid();
}
```

Comment: but that's printing every column twice in the grid view! what should i do

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["Candidates"];
            dt.Rows.Add(TextBox1.Text.Trim(), TextBox2.Text.Trim(),TextBox3.Text.Trim());
       -
            TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            TextBox2.Text = string.Empty;
            TextBox3.Text = string.Empty;

        }

        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void BindGrid()
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

    }
}
```